# change iframe href from a different domain with css, html, or javascript for internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an iframe where the src brings http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=155 time  but in my site when you click the time sends you straight to the site TimeAndDate. any way to remove the link to that lead me to this site? try with pointer-events: none, but only works for chrome and need it to work for internet explorer 8

Answer (score 1):

You're **not** allowed to read content served from another domain. This violates cross-domain policies.

You can imagine the potential for abuse: any website could open a window to facebook.com, and if you happen to be logged in, they can read all your personal info.

Comment: yup i know that i dont want to change it i just want to know if can disable de ref to that site in my site it works in chrome with the pointer-events so i want to know if there is a way to work on IE like pointer-events just to disable the ref on my site

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to stop user interaction to the site in the iframe? Overlay the iframe with a transparent div.

Comment: yup thats right just the interaction so the user that is on mi site can't click on the timer to refer to he's page

Comment: another solution? because the page have dinamic dimensions and the transparent div will block another data in the site if the site takes another dimension